# How to integrate this using tan(x/2) substitution?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How do I integrate cos(x)/(sqrt(5)+cos(x)) ?

I have been advised to use t = tan(x/2) substitution but ended up with a polynomial of degree 4 over one of degree 6 to integrate, which did not have an obvious solution.

Comment: Add and subtract $\sqrt5$ in the numerator.

Comment: You should post the integrand you got, to make it easier to help you, and to identify possible mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you express $\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{5}+\cos x}$ as $1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}+\cos x}$, and use the recommended substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ on the second term, you should end up integrating a constant over a quadratic.